# TestNG - @Test on constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, testng

I don't have the newest version of TestNG, and I have option to add `@Test` on constructor, [java docs](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/0f7e671c94aeedee2fbc796b3318d44b0297b6cd/src/main/java/org/testng/annotations/Test.java)

> ```
> @Target({METHOD, TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR}) 
> public @interface Test {
> ```

I didn't find any clue on usage in [docs](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) or searching online

> `@Test`    Marks a class or a method as part of the test.

When/Why `@Test` can be define on constructor? is it for internal purposes only?

I saw that CONSTRUCTOR was removed in latest TestNG version, but I didn't find why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See issue "[Remove irrelevant "targets" for TestNG annotations](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1484)": The target *CONSTRUCTOR* had no functionality in older versions, because constructors were not seen as test methods. That's why the target was removed later.